# GitHub Actions for firebase cli user/repository when its a repo is inside an organization

Tags: firebase, next.js, github-actions

I hosted a next js website on firebase using firebase cli successfully. Now I'm trying to configure github actions to deploy it automatically.

I am struck on this step:

*? For which GitHub repository would you like to set up a GitHub workflow? (format: user/repository)*

My repo is inside an organization and I don't know what to input here.

I tried user/org-name/repo-name , user/repo-name , org-name/repo-name , (org-name/repo-name) but it doesn't work. Please help.

For org-name/repo-name I am getting the following error.

```
Error: HTTP Error: 403, Policy update access denied.
```

Note: I'm the owner of the organization and I gave the necessary permissions.